# How does this Powershell Regex work?

Tags: regex, powershell

```
'<Relation From="701047080" ObjectNumber="166543300" Output="77" To="464616324">' -match '(?<=Output=")[^"]*'
```

`$matchs` then contains 77?

Which is what I want, I just don't understand why it works?

I've found stuff saying I could:

```
match '(?<NAME>Some regex)'
```

But I have no Idea what '(?<=' does?  And I would REALLY like to understand the syntax...

I actually need to pull out the value of Output and To both...  And only have powershell on the system I need to do this on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(?<=Output=")` is a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches only immediately after the string `Output="`.

The expression `[^"]*` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). It matches all characters until the next double-quote (or to the end of the string if there are no more double-quotes).

Comment: I understand the [^"]* part.  But thanks for giving a link that described the "lookbehind"  non of the searches I did on powershell regex explained that part.

Answer (score 3):

The `[^"]*` says any number of characters other than `"`.

The `[^"]*` is the main expression.

The `(?<=Output=")` is a lookbehind and makes sure that the main expression is following the expression in the lookbehind, in this case `Output="`. The lookbehind expression is not included in the match

**I don't think the regex is optimal.**

You could have used:

```
'<Relation From="701047080" ObjectNumber="166543300" Output="77" To="464616324">' -match 'Output="(.*?)"'
```

(with the regex being as simple as `Output="(.*?)"`)

and got the 77 in `$matches[1]`

The regex was probably just complicated with the lookbehind to make the `Output="` be not part of the match. It makes the regex more complex and reduces performance. All you need is the above regex and extract 77 with the appropriate group.

Comment: I liked your answer too, but I can only select one "correct answer."  Since I was asking to explain why it worked I decided providing a link to a description of what a lookbehind actually is was the more correct answer.  However, I like the simpler regex you showed me!  Thanks alot!